# Get the shortest path between a start point and end point in pgrouting

Tags: pgrouting

I want to find the shortest path for a start point and end point chosen by the user. How can I accomplish this in pgrouting. I have the latitude and longitude of the start point as well as for the end point. How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a quick search helps. This must have been answered at least one times. 
Anyway, take a look at the pgRouting workshop, which explains what you're asking for: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/php_server.html